# ASP.NET MVC Return Overloaded Get Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4, and I have the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeForm(modelType model = null)
{
    if(model != null)
       return View(model);
    return View(getModelFromSomewhere());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeForm(modelType model)
{
    if(isValid())
        doSomething();
    else
        return SomeForm(model) // Line in Question
}
```

However, obviously, I am getting an ambiguous method error on "Line in Question".  I'm wondering if anyone has an elegant solution to be able to specify to return specifically the [Get] method of the same name?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need methods to have the same name?

Comment: This does not look as a correct overloading, and won't compile anyway

Comment: Andrei, you're right that it doesn't compile because of the ambiguity.  I previously had [HttpGet] SomeForm(), but wanted to make a way to return the form with previously entered values rather than resetting them by doing a hard redirect via RedirectToAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have methods with the same signature as you've pointed out already. In C# it also means you can't distinguish functions by just return type - so you must use different names if parameters are same (again default values are ignored when matching of signatures).

If you want separate GET and POST handler - use different names of methods and [`ActionNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to name the action:

```
[HttpGet]
[AciontName("SomeForm")]
public ActionResult SomeFormGet(modelType model = null) ...

[HttpPost]
[AciontName("SomeForm")]
public ActionResult SomeFormPost(modelType model) ...
```

Comment: @chadiusvt, make sure to accept if that fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

make it compile...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeForm(modelType model, FormCollection fc)
{
    if(isValid())
        doSomething();
    else
        return SomeForm(model) // Line in Question
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  This would have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http `get` method you are waiting that browser will send you serialized model as a string query. For example, you are waiting url like

```
http://example.com?name=Andrew&type=Worker&field1=param1&field2=param2&....
```

It is common practice to use only `id` in your `get` method, so you can do it like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeForm(int id)
{
    var model = FindModelById(id);
    if(model != null)
       return View(model);
    return View(getModelFromSomewhere());
}
```

If you are looking for an elegant solution, it will be more elegant in architecture